# Rails catch-all/globbing routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3.0.14, and I am constructing routes.rb using the resourceful style. I'd like to have a wildcard route that catches all requests that do not match to any route stated.

What's the appropriate way to construct such a route?

Answer (score 33):

put

```
match '*path' => 'your_controller#your_action'
```

at the end of the routes.rb file. This is important, since the routes are stepped through top down.

See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html -> 3.10

Comment: Only for rails 3

Comment: You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.

Comment: You must append `, via: :all` (or the specific method you want to match)

Answer (score 32):

For Rail 4, you need to specify the request type:

```
match "*path", to: "application#custom_action", via: :all
```

As others have said, put this at the very bottom of your routes file.

Comment: Rails 4 catch-all that redirects to root `match "*path", to: redirect('/'), via: :all`

Comment: **NOTE:** `match "*path"` does not include `root` (for instances where you don't need to have `root` defined). You'll also need to add `root to: "application#custom_action", via: :all`

Answer (score 7):

It is not mandatory to use exactly "path" in the `match '*path'` statement. You can set a whatever token there:

```
get "*string1"
```

or

```
get "*string2"
```

Rails will assign your real HTTP-query to the param named after your token, example:

```
get "*user" => "users#show"
```

in console:

```
Started GET "/john" ....  
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML 
Parameters: {"user"=>"john"}
```

You can use more than one asterisks, say `get "*id*user"`. But in this case you will get some unpredictable result, because Rails processes 2 or more asterisks "in an intuitive way" - for more info see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @steel and @awenkhh, I recommend adding the following to that route's controller action

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  # other formats you already support
  format.all { render text: '' }
end
```

Otherwise, you'll wind up with some `ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template` errors for formats that you weren't expecting.

[rant]Particularly helpful for those people trying erroneous attack vectors around `/wp-admin/css/wp-admin.css` and the like.  I seem to get about 100 requests for `/wp-admin/*` a day, from super annoying people who apparently would like me to get a more expensive Rollbar account plan.[/rant]

Comment: Regarding the rant above, you can suppress those routing warnings in Rollbar (and not need the more expensive plan) by adding the following line into config/initializers/rollbar.rb (see comments in that file for more info): 

    config.exception_level_filters.merge!('ActionController::RoutingError' => 'ignore')

Comment: Hello @Paul I am using rails 6 with react view and i am rendering json from controller so react can catch it , but when i am using wildcard routes like this `get '*path', to: 'home#index', via: :all, format: false`, i am getting the similar error you mentioned `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template home/index`  and when i change format to true it works. But it breaks sometimes. Can you please help me what to do ? and