# Ruby on Rails database driven router to support fully customizable urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm planning to port our current cms (written in PHP) to Rails. All parts do well, except for one: routing.

Like most cms systems, the routing in our cms based on a database with pages, which are linked to modules, controllers and actions. On this approach a user can fully customize or specify it's own urls.

I know that Rails (and most (application) frameworks have the approach of defining routes in a file, but I hope this is possible.

The approach our users should have is:

1. add new page
2. select type (news, form, product, ...)
3. select an item (select which form, blog or product should be displayed)
4. enter a url for that page

Special the last point (4) is important. A user should be able to add form A to `/contact-us`, and form B to `/clients/register-as-new-client` e.g.

On a request the router needs to do a database query with the page url, to find out which controller, task and parameters should be dispatched.

Answer (score 1):

**Question has been updated, and i don't think this is a valid answer anymore**

we have a similar paging system. we use a routing glob. in routes.rb:

```rb
get 'pages/*lookup_path', to: 'pages#show', defaults: { format: 'html' }, as: 'page'
```

Just parse `params[:lookup_path]` in `PagesController` to suit your needs

```
'http://localhost/pages/users/'
  params[:lookup_path] #=> users/
'http://localhost/pages/users/23'
  params[:lookup_path] #=> users/23
'http://localhost/pages/people/1'
  params[:lookup_path] #=> people/1
```

Comment: But what if I want `http://localhost/about-us` to a PagesController, but `http://localhost/contact` to be ContactController (and, of course, define these urls in a database) ?

Comment: you could get rid of the "pages" prefix and move the route to the very last line of `routes.rb` and have it act as a catch-all

Comment: For me that would be totally okay, but our users want to create a new page, select the type (news, form, products, etc.), the id and type a url for that page.

Comment: and you have a `NewsController`,`ProductsController`, etc defined already?

Comment: Yes, i have. I updated my question to explain my situation a bit more, please take note of it.

Comment: Yes i did misunderstand the question. The system we have uses the `lookup_path` to find a bit of ruby code in the db. the code implements a component system to render the page. Its all done from 1 controller.

Answer (score 0):

Although this solution isn't ReSTful, I think this should solve the issue.

Regardless, Rails uses routes in a file. You cannot change this since the framework heralds "convention over configiuration". All I can do is point you in a direction to minimize this.

There is a catchall route in Rails (on [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/46-catch-all-route), and on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388715/rails-catch-all-route)) which you can use to direct all routing to one controller action. You may further customize the routing behaviour in that method

You could also make a route like…

```
:controller/:action => Controller::Action
```

…as is done in CodeIgniter, but now your methods have to have names like `contact-us` and `register-as-a-new-client`.