# User created custom URL with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-url

On our website, I'd like users to be able to create their own vanity/custom URL for marketing purposes (i.e. `www.website.com/cakeparty2015` actually goes to `www.website.com/cake/party-supplies/2015-inventory`).

This is NOT a custom user created page - it's an already existing page that it will route to. The only new information is the custom URL.

I don't really know if this is possible, but does anyone know of a way using Rails to have it so a user can log in and create their own vanity URL, say where it links, and then have that automatically re-route?

To be a little clearer - hopefully
I'd like a user to fill out a form containing:

Vanity URL -

Actual URL -

and when they submit this form, the newly created vanity URL links to the actual URL. I'd like to do this without having to put every single custom URL in my route file.

Perhaps I am looking at this wrong. I'm currently trying to figure out a way to do this with URL shortening possibly?

Comment: Maybe something like a catch-all route?  Look [at this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388715/rails-catch-all-route).  From there you'd just have to have your list of known custom URLs and their destinations, and redirect.

Comment: I currently have that. What I'm trying to do it make it so a user can create their own without me having to go into the code every time to update the custom URL list.

Comment: Oh, well you'd put them in the database, right?  Strip the incoming URL down to the custom portion, query the database for it, like `CustomRoute.find_by(name: name)`, and redirect or fail if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use https://github.com/norman/friendly_id.

You will then have a slug field in the model and you can let your users change it.

Comment: The problem with that is it requires me to know where they will be redirecting in the first place. I'd like the user to pick both the custom URL and where it will redirect. Unless I am misunderstanding how it works, with FriendlyId I would have to set up a slug field for every single index.