# Rails/WEBrick error page forwarding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, postman, webrick

I have a ruby-on-rails application running locally on a **WEBrick** server. I am using Postman to trigger HTTP Methods (POST, GET, etc) in order to check if any error page is shown to the users. The figure below shows one of the error pages found when performing a POST to the home page:

[WEBrick Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvnwf.png)

As one can note, the physical path to the application directory is disclosed: /home/dennis/dunbarwebsite

Leaking this kind of information may help one fine-tune attacks against the application. Hence, I would like to know if it is possible to forward this error page to a custom one, like the custom redirection to errors 404 and 500.

Thanks in advance,
Dennis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That error page only appears in development mode.
2. Add a [catchall route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388715/rails-catch-all-route) at the end of `routes.rb`:

`match "*path", to: redirect('/'), via: :all`

Comment: I actually already had a similar catchall route:
match "*path", to: redirect('/'), via: :all

I changed to yours but it didn't work.

I found something related to your first point: I set config.consider_all_requests_local to false in config/development.rb. This variable is set to true in production.

Thanks!