# Ruby-on-Rails: route for path with arbitrary number of components?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes

In my `ror` application, I want to define a route that will dispatch any length path to a given handler.

I want any URL which begins with `http://example.com/xyz/...` to go to the same handler, with the full path being passed in as an argument.

In other words, any and all of the following URL's should go to the same handler for the `xyz` route ...

- `http://example.com/xyz`
- `http://example.com/xyz/foo`
- `http://example.com/xyz/foo/bar`
- `http://example.com/xyz/quack/bark/oink`
- `http://example.com/xyz/hip/po/pot/a/mus`
- `http://example.com/xyz/[any arbitrary path with any number of components]`

... and within the handler, I need to be able to retrieve the entire path that was submitted.

I thought that I should put something like this into `config/routes.rb` ...

```
get "xyz/[what goes here?]", to: "xyz#handler"
```

... but I could not figure out any way to make this work in `ror`.

In `flask`, I can set up a route which looks like this ...

```
/xyz/<path:pathvar>
```

... and the entire path which appears after `/xyz` will be available to the handler within the `pathvar` variable. Is there any kind of analog to this in `ror`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I found the answer here: [Rails catch-all route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388715/rails-catch-all-route)

I just do this ...

```
get "xyz/*pathvar", to: "xyz#handler"
```

... and the full path that appears after `/xyz` will appear in `params['pathvar']`.