# Default 404 page won't display anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Recently I tried to set up a custom 404 page using this guide:

https://thepugautomatic.com/2014/08/404-with-rails-4/

It ended up not working, so I reverted all the changes, recreated the default 404 page in the /public folder, and customised it from there, but it will now only load when visiting /404 directly, and won't display when going to another unlisted route (i.e. localhost:3000/foo). Instead I get a blank white page with "Not Found" displayed in the top left-hand corner. I thought this may have been coming from `/node_modules/builtin-status-codes/browser.js` where it has a list of errors including `"404": "Not Found"`.

I've been through the code multiple times with a fine-toothed comb but I cannot figure out why it won't work in it's default settings anymore. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you want display your custom 404 page whenever going to unlisted routes, you must catch all them (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388715/rails-catch-all-route).

Comment: @LamPhan That link didn't really help - I ended up getting different errors. Isn't rails already set up to display the /public/404.html page by default when trying to get unlisted routes? I didn't think I'd need to set up a catch-all